# Programmatically scroll in increments

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I'm trying to create a scroll view that will scroll up by the length of the page upon a swipe of any sort. Basically, I never want the view to have partially cut of content. My approach was to create a custom class that extends ScrollView but I'm running into issues but the main issue is how to detect upward and downward swipes. Any help or idea of an approach would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Simply set a scroll listener to the scrollview, listen for `STATE_IDLE` and adjust view position by calling scroll to the expected position. You will need to calculate the expected position where the view is not cut into.

Comment: How can I tell whether it was a scroll up or scroll down?

Comment: You don't need to know... You just need to know which child-view you need adjusted by scrolling e.g. when the scroll ends you can check which child-view takes more space on screen and just scroll towards it.